# Switch to previous vim buffer that is not unlisted

Tags: vim

Is there a convenient way to switch to the previous (most recently viewed) buffer *that is not unlisted*? `C-^` and `:e#<CR>` will take me to the previous buffer – whether it's unlisted or not – but I never want to edit unlisted buffers.

Comment: `bnext` and `bprev`?

Comment: I went nuts with just this problem, finally wrote a solution, you can find it in [myDotfiles](https://github.com/davidsu/dotfiles/blob/master/config/nvim/autoload/utils.vim#L185) and [how to use](https://github.com/davidsu/dotfiles/blob/master/config/nvim/startup/leader_mappings.vim#L39), hope it helps

Comment: @sudavid4 thanks! Why not add it as an answer and I'll accept it if no one can propose a builtin way in the next few days.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo bnext/bprev cycle through buffers in number order, not mru order.

Answer (score 0):

I went nuts with just this problem, finally wrote a solution, you can find it in [myDotfiles](https://github.com/davidsu/dotfiles/blob/master/config/nvim/autoload/utils.vim#L185) and [how to use](https://github.com/davidsu/dotfiles/blob/master/config/nvim/startup/leader_mappings.vim#L39), hope it helps

Comment: I looked at your function more closely yesterday. It ignores certain kinds of buffers (quicklist, terminal, man) when jumping back but afaict it doesn't maintain MRU ordering. Do you agree? I see that you have a function `utils#list_buffers` which could be used to help do the job, but it depends on fzf. Looking at the fzf and CtrlP code has convinced me that there's no other way to do this but to maintain the MRU list based on bufenter etc. autocommands, so I've written a function to do that accordingly.

Comment: I don't see the relation. I'm using `utils#buffers_listed`, there is a `s:list_buffers` function in this file(that depends on `fzf`) but it's not used for `utils#restoreAlternateFile`. Doesn't it maintain MRU? I see it allways jumping back to where I'd expect it to, it's been over a year since I wrote these stuff though, I don't remember all the details.